# JQ hex string conversion to ASCII

Tags: string, type-conversion, jq

I end up in jq with a hex string that I want to convert to ASCII, within jq. Doing it outside would involve passing multiple conditions too, which over complicates matters and would really slow down the solution.

To be clear: it concerns a string translation like:

```
"0x4162634b6c6d" -> "AbcKlm"
```

stripping of the "0x" is easy ( .[2:] ) and I got the equivalent in a bash function:

```
function h2a () 
{ 
    while read s; do
        n=0;
        while [[ "$n" -lt ${#s} ]]; do
            h="${s:$n:2}";
            printf "\x$h";
            n="$(($n+2))";
        done;
    done
}
```

but I would really want to do this in native jq. I found [Rosetta JQ](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Jq), but am unable to convert.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: making progress, found [how to access substrings](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1520)
Now, how do I convert and iterate?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function like this:

```
def decode_hex:
    ("0123456789abcdef"|split("")|with_entries({key:.value, value:.key})) as $hex_map |
    def decode_nybble: $hex_map[ascii_downcase];
    def decode_byte: (.[0:1]|decode_nybble * 16) + (.[1:2]|decode_nybble);
    def pairs: range(0;length;2) as $i | .[$i:$i+2];
    [pairs|decode_byte] | implode;
```

Then to use it, strip out any non-hex characters and pass the string in.

```
.[2:] | decode_hex
```

Interesting side notes, strings are handled very differently compared to arrays to my surprise. You cannot index into them directly or perform other similar array-like operations on them. You can see how awkward it can be by looking at how `$hex_map` and `decode_byte` was defined above.

Comment: doing `("0123456789abcdef"|split("")|with_entries({key:.value, value:.key})) as $hex_map` outside of `decode_hex` makes this faster

Comment: Sure, but you run the risk of `$hex_map` being redefined. Technically, all functions could as well. This keeps it all in a nice package.

Answer (score 2):

If an efficient solution is needed, then piggy-backing off @JeffMercado's answer:

```
def decode_hex:
  def decode: if . < 58 then .-48 elif . < 91 then .-55 else .-87 end;
  def decode_byte: map(decode) | (.[0] * 16) + .[1];
  def pairs: explode | range(0;length;2) as $i | [.[$i], .[$i+1]];
  [pairs|decode_byte] | implode;
```

Comment: A solution that handles non-printable characters would be nice, e. g. replacing them by `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Further extending @peak's answer and adding @stackprotector suggestion to filter out non-printable characters:

```
def decode_hex:
  def decode: if . < 58 then .-48 elif . < 91 then .-55 else .-87 end;
  def decode_byte: map(decode) | (.[0] * 16) + .[1];
  def pairs: explode | range(0;length;2) as $i | [.[$i], .[$i+1]];
  def filter: if (. < 32 or (. >= 128 and . <= 159)) then 46 else . end;
  [pairs|decode_byte|filter] | implode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat q6.jq 
{ "b": 
   [(
     { "a": (split("")) }
     | .a[] 
     | gsub ("a"; "10"; "i") | gsub ("b"; "11"; "i") | gsub ("c"; "12"; "i") | gsub ("d"; "13"; "i") | gsub ("e"; "14"; "i") | gsub ("f"; "15"; "i")
    )
   ]
} 
| { "a": [ .b as $m | range(0; $m | length; 2) | { "q" : [ ($m[.]|tonumber),  ($m[(. + 1)]|tonumber) ] } ] } |
[ (.a[].q) as $b | (($b[0]) * 16) as $d | ($b[1]) as $e | ($d+$e) ] | implode

$ echo '"4162634b6c6d"' | jq -f q6.jq
"AbcKlm"
$
```

Yes, I know, it's ugly, twice the size of the bash function and it works. If you can improve: please show us.

Answer (score 0):

Use this filter to convert input hex string to number:

```
reduce explode[] as $n (0; . * 16 + ($n - 48) % 39)
```

---

```
$ echo ff | jq -R 'reduce explode[] as $n (0; . * 16 + ($n - 48) % 39)'
255
```